# Why does column take precedence over an object with the same name in data table in cases of join with a subsetted data table

Tags: r, data.table

```
test <- function() {
  operator_descriptions <- data.table(operator = "/", description = "/")
  operator_conditions <- data.table(operator = "/", condition = "Quotient non zero")
  condition <- c(TRUE)
  operator_conditions[operator_descriptions[condition], on = c("operator")]
}

test()
```

```
Output
Error: When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

Despite the fact that condition is in the scope of `operator_descriptions`, `condition` column of `operator_conditions` seems to take precedence over the `condition` object defined in previous statement.

This behavior requires one to be cautious about names etc. While in normal cases, this is fine as we intend to use column names mostly. But in cases like these, I am not sure if it is the intention.

Comment: It's interesting to me that both `operator_descriptions[condition]` and `operator_conditions[operator_descriptions, on="operator"]` work without issue, yet (as you demonstrate) the merge fails.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Within the scope of `operator_conditions`, the column `condition` is defined, while it is not so for `operator_descriptions[condition]`.

Comment: I think this is worth bringing to the [`data.table/issues`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/) crowd.

Comment: Added the issue : https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4946

Comment: @r2evans I agree with this comment. What's ur take ? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4946#issuecomment-809368010